# Running RNTester

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am getting into React Native. I want to try running RNTester to check out the components they have. I had no issue runnning my other react project. 
I tried the commands:

- git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git
- cd    react-native
- npm install

and also run the project with open RNTester/RNTester.xcodeproj

The errors I got:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4KOA.png)

my Xcode version: 9.0(9C40b)
clang version: Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)

Comment: follow this doc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933836/running-rntester

Comment: @RY_Zheng That link just points to this post

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running with RNTester.xcodeproj

I got around with CocoaPods.

- run pod install in the RNTester folder
- run the .xcworkspace file generated from the command